# Difference between کذب and باطل?

Tags: quran, arabic

What is the difference between کذب and باطل in context of Quran and Arabic?

I was seeking the word about **False** or **Falsehood**. And I found these two words, **Kizb** and **Batl** or Batil. I want to know exact meanings of them. How they are different and how they are related.

کذب vs باطل

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Kizb** is the act of *Saying* something false.

**Batl** anything that is not true.(including kizb)

---

language usage Examples:

> أحمد أخبر المدرسة بأنه مريض ليغيب من المدرسة. لقد **كذب**

Ahmed told the teacher he is sick, to skip the school. He **lied**

> لقد زور هذا الرجل فوزه في الانتخابات. إن فوزه **باطل**

This man has manipulated the elections to win. His win Is **False**

> انت تقول أن الخفاش من الطيور. وهذا كلام **باطل**

you are saying that the bat is a bird. This is **false**

> لقد **كذب** "مسيلمة الكذاب" على الناس. إن نبوته **باطلة**

[Musaylimah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musaylimah) "the layer" has **lied** to the people. His prophet-hood is **False**